# phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner not support PWA, it's shows Cordova not available

Tags: reactjs, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

please anyone tell me how to use this plugin for web. i try many plugins but not work for me or on my scenario.
phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner is the perfect plugin, worked on native( android and IOS) but not work on Web.
error is "Cordova not available"

Answer (score 0):

After build web directory you need execute "npx cap sync web" command, [how implement web in Capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/web#using-capacitor-as-a-script-include)

Event though your error is in Cordova and not is Capacitor, maybe the plugin is not correctly implemented, please read how to implement in Capacitor [barcode-scanner](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner)